# Google Advanced Protection on macOS Sierra, Internet Accounts is broken

Tags: google-chrome, u2f

I recently signed up for Google Advanced Protection & enabled it using my MacBook running macOS Sierra, 10.12.6.  Periodically I get notices from Internet Accounts to sign into Google, except I can't.  I enter my account name & password then a message pops up saying I can only use my security keys with Chrome.  If I try to use another method the only option I'm given is the same U2F key I was just told I couldn't use.  So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: There were changes with the login functionality in 69.x  (https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2018/09/25/users-fret-over-chrome-auto-login-change/).  Could you try to downgrade to 68.x and try it again?

Comment: Chrome 68 installed side-by-side with current.  I can login to Google with AP enabled, but when I go to Internet Accounts & try there, same thing - "You can only use your Security Keys with Google Chrome."

Comment: Went & deleted current Chrome altogether, same result.

Comment: Hmm that is probably a bug.  Could you try the following? 1) open the dev tools (maybe you can use agent-switcher too https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-g/ffhkkpnppgnfaobgihpdblnhmmbodake)
2) select the user agent to Android
3) login and select "I'm having trouble"
4) select google Authenticator and log-in

Comment: agent-switcher added, lots of others available but android is greyed out.

Comment: So it looks like Android is a group, selectable options in that group are Nexus 7, Galaxy S3 & Galaxy Tab.  Nexus 7 OK?

Comment: Not seeing any difference in IA from switching UA in Chrome.  Same behavior, security key is my only 2FA option no matter what, it always says "You can only use your Security Keys with Google Chrome." but never accepts that my key is in the USB & completes the process.